# Mysql Update column with percentage from other tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am currently still learning mysql so forgive me if I am doing something wrong.

For learning purposes I am making a database of stats from a game I play. I've wrote a script that parses data from a website and then uploads the data to mysql based on the season. I then have a totals table that I use for the data aggregate.

I can't figure out however how to make a column that shows the progression for a player compared to the last season (with season 12 being the current season in my example).

I tried this, but the query takes way too long and I've never been able to see the outcome due to impatience and the fact that I read that subqueries are inefficient and that I should be avoiding them.

```
update totals
set `Season Performance` =
(select round((season12.`Average Match Score` / season11.`Average Match Score`) * 100)
from season12,season11
where totals.`Pilot Name` = season12.`Pilot Name` AND  season11.`Pilot Name` = season12.`Pilot Name`  LIMIT 1);
```

The goal, is to update the table with the name totals by checking season 11 and 12 for players that played and then giving performance.

Totals however is all seasons so there are some players not in season 11 or 12.

Comment: Are your tables indexed on the columns you're using for the ``SELECT`` and ``JOIN``?

Comment: I'm still learning too. So, forgiven.

Comment: Any time you have enumerated columns/tables you can be SURE that something has gone very, very wrong with your schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than a subquery like that, I would rewrite it somethinglike like this (not tested for syntax):

```
UPDATE totals INNER JOIN
(
SELECT season12.`Pilot Name`, ROUND((season12.`Average Match Score` / season11.`Average Match Score`) * 100) AS the_perc
FROM season12 INNER JOIN season11 ON season11.`Pilot Name` = season12.`Pilot Name`
) a ON totals.`Pilot Name` = a.`Pilot Name`
SET totals.`Season Performance` = a.the_perc
```

and make sure there is an index on `Pilot Name`

Comment: Thanks for the help Riedsio. Yeah, there is a problem with "a" for syntax. I think there needs to be an alias set up but I am not sure where.




    syntax error near 'ON season11.`Pilot Name` = season12.`Pilot Name` ) a ON totals.`Pilot Name` = a' at line 4"`

Comment: Updated.  You were using a comma instead of my reflex "INNER JOIN"

Comment: I very much appreciate your help. I am starting to see what you are doing in your example (creating a temp join table first). However, it looks like there is a precedence issue with this new table as I am getting an error #1054 - Unknown column 'a.Pilot Name' in 'on clause'

Comment: updated again. just missing the field name in the temp table required for the join